# Using ChatGPT to submit an assignment, a Buddhist perspective

Tags: karma, ethics, precept

Was trying to help an undergrad with his assignment with another friend. This friend started advising the undergrad to use [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com) to do his assignments while the undergrad was complaining that it wasn’t very helpful for his programming module. I felt uneasy but the way the conversation went, this seems like a common thing. So, I am not sure.

I wondered what is the correct Buddhist view on this. Is it breaking any precepts like lying (this is cheating, right?). Will it lead to long lasting harm and suffering from a karmic point of view? What would be the Buddha’s advice?

Comment: Why not ask the student's teacher -- what programming tools is the student allowed to use? -- or I expect the student probably knows already. Are they allow/expected to use "AI" or is that forbidden -- because whether there's deception depends on whether it's forbidden by the teacher's rules+expectations.

Comment: Is even education acceptable by Buddhism?

Comment: *Are they allow/expected to use "AI"*....I get a feeling that the students today only think it is **cheating** if they are caught. 

Comment: @Qwerty I don't know.... perhaps you can ask this question in the forum.

Comment: Wanting to "cheat" academically might be a symptom that the student wants to pass the exam or get a high grade, but without doing the work/practice and therefore learning the subject. When I was at school the purpose there seemed to be to do well at competitive exams. When I left school and began to do real, useful, interesting work, that's when I wanted to learn the subject.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same problem as a student. Perhaps, I am trying to think of a way to convince the undergrad (as well as myself) that it is the understanding part rather than the rushing to complete something (be it an assignment or project) that will put a person in good stead both now and in the future. It's just the way our society is setup (both in schools and work places) to reward speed and quantity that makes it extra difficult to come up with a convincing story.

Comment: FYI I read a psych experiment where two groups of young children were given a task, and then another more difficult task. After the first task, some were praised for their success (how well they completed it) and some were praised for their diligence (how well they focussed or how hard they worked). It was the second group that did better on the next task -- the first group would tend to give up (maybe thinking that, "If I can't succeed at this easily then this task isn't worth attempting").

Comment: Yes, they should teach this in school.  And repeat it at each level....getting the process right. The results are not always within our influence but it is usually easier to exert control on the process. And this skill of focusing on the process is also far more beneficial in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

The Buddha lived 2600 years and obviously gave no advice on ChatGPT.

This said, of course it is cheating. The bad karma involved is not learning how to study & research properly, which will lead to future academic & vocational failures in (the present) life.

It is similar to those who cannot study the Pali Suttas properly. They spend their time on 'Buddhist' chatsites making bad kamma & reviling the Noble Ones. Instead of studying the words of the Buddha, they use chatsites like a ChatGPT. The Dhammapada says:

> 50. Let none find fault with others; let none see the omissions and commissions of others. But let one see one's own acts, done and
>     undone.

Comment: Sadly, I have to downvote this answer. Yes, ChatGPT did not exist in the Buddha’s time but the issue of cheating is the same which we can address by applying insights from the Dharma. Not learning how to study or research properly is not bad karma. There are many people in the world that are bad at studying and cannot do proper research, it is condescending to think there is something wrong with them. It is when cheating becomes habitual (which usually happens) then it becomes **bad**.

Comment: While it is admirable that you are knowledgeable in Pali, linking the lack of this knowledge as not studying the sutras or the words of the Buddha properly, making bad karma and reviling the noble ones are presumptuous. Learning and remembering the Dharma is good but practising it is better. Many of the Buddha's Arahant disciples were illiterate. The above is why I downvoted although I observed that you don’t extend the same courtesy when downvoting. Just a friendly advice, habit is karma and good habits lead to good karma and vice versa.

Comment: Practise cannot occur without right learning. Please avoid nonsensical advice.